# usepackage{pdfpages} error

Tags: pdfpages

I use LaTeX using TeXShop in mac OS 10.8.5.

When I use `\usepackage{pdfpages}`, compile does not work and displays the message as shown in the image below.

How can I solve this error?

[image]

Comment: The error says you're missing the `\begin{document}` line. Could you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can have a look? Or, if you're wondering about the error, could you post a minimal document which reproduces that error?

Comment: Your document is loading a dvipdfmx and a dvips driver - which probably mean that  your script doesn't create a pdf directly but a dvi and so you can't use pdfpages.